# Querying Meteor.users() through Mongo php

Tags: php, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to query the Meteor.users() collection in php. I am so far able to get the users ID by using the email address. Now I want to add the password to the query but can't get the query constructed correctly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
try {
    $mongoDb = $mongoConn->xxxxxxxx;
    $collection = $mongoDb->users;
    //$userQuery = array('emails.address' => $user, "services" => array ( "password" =>  array( "bcrypt"  => $pass )));
    $userQuery = array('emails.address' => $user);
    $arr = $collection->findOne($userQuery);
} catch (MongoException $e) {
    die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
$id = $arr[_id];
```

Here is how the password portion is setup in Mongo:

```
"services" : {
    "password" : {
      "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$lYaK1PDTmRTvpddOX5R08Ooupdczktve/qgUMhFvwKfvpPUk3kEH2"
  } 
},
"emails" : [{
  "address" : "demo@demo.com",
  "verified" : false
}]
```

I've tried different combinations of dot notation and bracket notation for `services=>password=>bcrypt` but I'm so far unable to get in there. Any ideas on how to query that part?

Answer (score 0):

The ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) syntax is exactly the same as what you did for the array element in the document. So:

```
    $userQuery = array(
       'emails.address' => $user,
       'services.password.bcrypt' => $pass
    );
```

That said, your previous attempt:

```
"services" => array ( "password" =>  array( "bcrypt"  => $pass ))
```

Should work, but with the caveat that the object in the document "must be an exact match" of the represented structure with no other "sub-keys" present, since that is what you are asking the query engine to ask for.

The only other problem you could likely be facing is if you are working from a "plain text" password as input, then the encrypted string you are generating does not match the one that is stored.

In the latter case you will need to test your encrypted generation to find the method that uses exactly the same encryption hashing as what is being used to store the data. But that is an entirely different question to the syntax used to "query" the data.

Comment: I tried the dot notation first without success. I'm setting up $pass to be an exact match to the encrypted password. Here is part of the print_r when I use just the email address. `[services] => Array ( [password] => Array ( [bcrypt] => $2a$1..... )`.

Comment: @LeojPyzynski Supected as much. Your "question" is about "querying", your "problem" seems to be about misatched data. The query syntax as shown works fine for the rest of the world. Any other problem is your problem or another question entirely.

Comment: I'll try changing the password string to plain text and see what happens.

Comment: @LeojPyzynski That would be a good idea. It does help to debug things.